# Is there a way to specify the destination folder when you use the /copy parameter in a google docs URL?

Tags: google-docs

Google docs has a great feature that replacing the /edit with /copy in a google docs/sheets/slides URL prompts the user to make a copy.

I'd like the copy to remain in the document's original folder rather than making a copy in the users gdrive.

Any way to either specify the 'copy in place' behavior or the destination folder?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - posting to help others.

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<UUID OF FILE TO COPY>/copy?copyDestination=<UUID OF DESTINATION FOLDER>
```

for example (non working example)
To make a copy of `1xdd6pDLlid2loRcyyuhwULkycQnfcyr4r2q4bLTJVM`
into folder `ls1l28BLf1eD3mrP9llMbIkSMH0XLTu1k`

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xdd6pDLlid2loRcyyuhwULkycQnfcyr4r2q4bLTJVM/copy?copyDestination=ls1l28BLf1eD3mrP9llMbIkSMH0XLTu1k`

(tip of the hat to [the comments here](https://hellotumo.com/typings/how-to-guides/organizeyness-how-to-create-a-new-google-document-spreadsheet-or-form-in-a-specific-google-drive-folder/))

enjoy!